# What's a landing page?

Tags: seo, landing-page

The marketing team says I need a landing page.  What is that and why should I bother?

Comment: If the marketing team can't answer this question for you, they're not qualified to tell you that you need one.

Comment: This question was one posted as part of the initial seeding of the site meant for search bait, not a serious question from an actual marketing team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**LANDING PAGES**

Landing pages are highly optimized web pages that produce better results than the average web page.

There are two type of landing pages:

**1**) Content landing page, optimized to cover a specific question or task with loads of great content. These are made for search engines and users. (Great for indexing and organic search)

**2**) Task Landing pages, optimized for a very specific task. These pages are tested over time with A/B testing and Heat Mapping (And changed based on test results). Built around users and search.(Normally used with PPC Ads)

As far as marketing goes. The thing to be understand here is that landing pages are built for someone other than you. They are build around what makes action happen. The action they produce is what you are optimizing for.

**MOST IMPORTANT**: Landing pages have a very focused "call to action". If a Landing page doesn't ask you to do something, read more or contact us for example,  it is not a landing page.

Answer (score 6):

A [landing page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page) is the page that appears when a user clicks on an ad.  It can be a bit more targeted than just your home page.

Comment: They generally contain details related to the advertisement you've clicked on so that the user can connect between the ad they clicked on and your product. If you just dumped them on the home page they might have a "wtf" moment and leave