# How bad is it to call a landing page "landing.html"?

Tags: seo, landing-page, filenames, site-structure

I want a [landing page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/343/whats-a-landing-page) whose URL will be emailed after a few days to people who have downloaded my software. The landing page asks them how happy they are with the software, links to tutorials, and subtly hints at the paid support option.

My web team has created it with the name `TheSite.com/landing.html`.

Could it have bad effects? (SEO, reader's perception, aesthetics, etc)

What is usually considered a "good" URL for a landing page? (in particular referring to my case)

Analysis of real-world examples would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no good URL.  It is, as you say just perception.  If you don't like it, get your web people to change it, that is what you pay them for isn't it?

Comment: Just change it if you think it looks bad.   `/widget.html` or `/widget-brochure.html` or `/widget-info.html` might describe it better.

Comment: I would wrap it into your support section, support.example.com/index.php etc. then visitors won't realize it's targeted marketing

Answer (score 1):

What keywords did you want the page optimised for in organic search?

You can name a page you don't care about whatever you like. Your primary channel appears to be e-mails rather than search engines. Focus on user experience and associated metrics instead of SEO.

If you wanted it to show up on a search for 'Your company landing page' then optimise around that. Here's [an SEO cheatsheet](https://d2eeipcrcdle6.cloudfront.net/seo-cheat-sheet.pdf) that will get you started with naming conventions and importance. The file name **does** factor into optimisation. Just make sure what you're optimising it for is clear before you start.

Answer (score 0):

Well generally the landing page is called "index.html". But personally I don't think name of the pages really matter, because customers are only attracted by seeing the domain name.

Answer (score -1):

From seo point of view filename doesnt matter. It can only influence behavior of some people (people who notice this)